# Creating an array with IFS set to a different value

Tags: bash, string, array

I am trying to construct an array and write to a file in this format, i.e. the file's content should be something like this

```
hero_pairscore=( askdjfh sdf,sdlkfj lksf,dfgdf,dsflkgj,asdlkf ....)
```

Where the elements are separated by `comma`. I wrote the following code for this.

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x

hero_pairscore=()
while read line
do

$( IFS=",";hero_pairscore+=( "$line" )
done < true_pairscore.txt

echo "hero_pairscore=( ${hero_pairscore[@]} )" > embed.txt
```

But the resultant file contains only this `hero_pairscore=( )`. What is wrong with my code and how can I correct it to give the desired output?

Comment: Does the true_pairscore.txt file contain the "hero_pairscore=(" text??

Answer (score 6):

All you need to do here is this:

1. Set the variable. We'll use this:

   ```
   var="kijhg, fbjhku,,,ioy  fbjfr, kjmyhg"
   ```
2. Set the `$IFS` and prevent filename expansion:

   ```
   IFS=, ; set -f
   ```
3. `set` shell `$@`array to output.

   ```
   set -- $var
   ```
4. Reset parent shell `$IFS` and shell params:

   ```
   unset IFS ; set +f
   ```
5. Hooray! It even preserves multiple repeats and spaces and all!

   ```
   printf %s\\n "$@"
   ```

   OUTPUT

   ```
   kijhg
    fbjhku


   ioy  fbjfr
    kjmyhg
   ```

Anyway, take my word for it. Every character that is not a `,` is preserved.

#### TRANSFORM

I especially recommend using the real shell array as opposed to the bash array because you can instantly transform its splitter.

```
printf %s "$*"

#OUTPUT#
kijhg  fbjhku   ioy  fbjfr  kjmyhg %

IFS=, ; printf %s "$*"

#OUTPUT#
kijhg, fbjhku,,,ioy  fbjfr, kjmyhg
```

Because `$*` has the special POSIX-specified quality of splitting the shell's positional parameter argument array on the first character of `$IFS` you can easily convert swathes of data as simply as that. You can `"quote"`-protect the argument array and still split it on any single character you like. As long as you get it right the first time, that is.

#### APPEND/PREPEND

POSIX also specifies special qualities to `"$@"`. Aside from the `"$1"... eval "\${$#}"` addressing forms for each argument, the `"$@"` parameter - when quoted - safely expands to all of the shell's arguments as they were last `set` regardless of the current value of `$IFS.` So if you want to add a list to the beginning of your array you do:

```
set -- $list "$@"
```

To the head/tail:

```
set -- $head "$@" $tail
```

To triple your array:

```
set -- "$@" "$@" "$@"
```

#### ALTOGETHER NOW

Unless your datastream is very large, the following might be a little quicker than your current operation *(though, if you're working with files, you'd be far better off to eschew shell splitting altogether)*:

```
( set -f -- ; IFS=, ; while read -r line ; do set -- "$@" $line ; done
printf %s "$*" ) | cat >out
```

#### MAYBE TR?

What I don't understand though is this - just what are you doing? Are you trying to replace newlines with commas? I mean - **is the data already comma separated excepting only newlines?** If so:

```
tr '\n' ',' <in >out
```

Answer (score 5):

To do what I *think* you are trying to do, which is read every comma separated field in `true_pairscore.txt` into an array variable there is not much wrong with your code. The `$(` at the start of the `IFS` line is obviously wrong and would cause the script to have an error (maybe this is the reason you get no output). Other than that, the main fix for your code would be just to remove the quotes around `$line` since you want `bash` to do word splitting around `IFS` (usually this is what you use them to avoid):

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o noglob
OIFS=$IFS
IFS=","
hero_pairscore=()

while IFS= read -r line
do
  hero_pairscore+=( $line )
done < true_pairscore.txt

echo "hero_pairscore=( ${hero_pairscore[@]} )" > embed.txt

set +o noglob
IFS=$OIFS
```

However, here is a trick to do the above in only two lines:

```
IFS=$',\n' read -ra hero_pairscore -d '' <true_pairscore.txt
echo "hero_pairscore=( ${hero_pairscore[@]} )" > embed.txt
```

#### Update

If the `embed.txt` file is to be sourced in another `bash` shell, you probably want to quote each element of the written `hero_pairscore` array. To do this, replace the `echo "hero_pairscore=( ${hero_pairscore[@]} )"` with:

```
echo "hero_pairscore=( $(printf '"%s" ' "${hero_pairscore[@]}") )"
```